# Is possible to create a panel with GBIF databases?

Tags: r, database, biometrics

Good evening to anyone!, I'm interested in a study of biodiversity and GBIF is helping a lot. I'm kinda new into GIS and its linkages with R. I found a database of observations in GBIF that have all data I need, but I wanted to agreggate previous versions of it (as it is updated to June/2023 and I'm interested in data since 2018).I was looking for information about something similar into blogs and forums, but I just found basic codes for occurence plotting. So if anyone knows something about this, please let me know.

scentially I started looking for something into GBIF webpage and found nothing, after that I switched to Rgbif, but got stucked by now.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.